# Bootstrap carousel not working in angular (10)

Tags: angular

Here in the below code I fetched async data from component and load in to template. But carousel is not working with async data. However if I place static code in the template file then it works...

```
<div id="product_details_slider" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li class="" *ngFor="let img of gallImgs;let i=index" data-slide-to="{{i}}"  data-target="#product_details_slider"  style="background-image: url({{img}});">
    </li>
            
</ol>
<div class="carousel-inner">
<div class="carousel-item" *ngFor="let img of gallImgs">
<a class="gallery_img" href="{{img}}">
<img class="d-block w-100" src="{{img}}" alt="First slide">
</a>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Awaiting code paste. Put a console.log of your async data and make sure it matches up with the static code. There's a chance your async data is not the same

Comment: You didn't include any code.  But are you either using the async pipe or subscribing to the your data-acquisition observable and storing your data in an array in the callback? But not both.